# MODX: display elements in groups by two with wrapper for every group

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource

Imagine situation when you need to have output like this

```
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">First resource</td>
        <td class="cell">Second resource</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">Third resource</td>
        <td class="cell">Fourth resource</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">Fifth resource</td>
        <td class="cell">Sixth resource</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><!--groups-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            First resource
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Second resource
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><!--group-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Third resource
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Fourth resource
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>

    <div><!--group-->
        ...
    </div>

    ...
    ...
</div>
```

As for me this structures are similar for my purpose. I was looking for examples of the usage of **placeholders**, but do not get it. Please write the example with getResources or PDOTools or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`0`
    &depth=`1`
    &tplFirst=`tplFirst`
    &tpl=`tpl`
    &tplOdd=`tplOdd`
    &tplLast=`tplLast`
    &tplWrapper=`tplWrapper`
]]
```

tplFirst

```
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell">[[+pagetitle]]</td>
```

tpl

```
        <td class="cell">[[+pagetitle]]</td>
```

tplOdd

```
        <td class="cell">[[+pagetitle]]</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row">
```

tplLast

```
        <td class="cell">[[+pagetitle]]</td>
    </tr>
```

tplWrapper

```
<table>
    [[+output]]
</table>
```